# Count sides of 1's in matrix which it shares with 0

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, depth-first-search

We have a matrix which contains 0 and 1.

Similar to number of island problem.

I need to find out the total sides(left,right,up,down) which 1 shares with 0's and with outer world(that is boundary of the matrix).

Example:

```
     1 0 1 0 0
     1 1 1 0 1
     0 1 0 0 0
     1 0 0 0 0
```

So,  14 + 4 + 4 = 22

14 from first group

4 from other 2 groups

We need to find out length where island touches with 0 or matrix boundary.
In example there are 3 island and two of them are single 1. So they touches 0 and matrix boundary with all there four sides (up,down,right and left).
And 3rd island consist of 6 1's and adding all 1's sides out of 4 sides which 1's share common with 0 and matrix boundary are 14.

This is my code.

```
class graphe:
def __init__(self,row,col,g):
    self.row=row
    self.col=col
    self.graph=g

def valid(self,i,j):
    return (i>=0 and i < self.row and j>=0 and j< self.col )


def dfs(self,t):
    r = [0,0,1,-1]
    c = [1,-1,0,0]
    total = 0
    for ii in t:
        i = ii[0]
        j = ii[1]
        for k in range(4):
            if self.valid(i+r[k],j+c[k]):
                if self.graph[i+r[k]][j+c[k]] == 0:
                    total += 1
            else:
                total += 1
    return total


for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,m,k = map(int,input().split())
    graph = [ [0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
    t = []
    for i in range(k):
        a,b = map(int,input().split())
        graph[a-1][b-1] = 1
        t.append([a-1,b-1])

    g = graphe(n,m,graph)

    print(g.dfs(t))
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about groups. Just analyze each 1 separately.

Comment: I need to decrease the time. I applied simple bfs and checked all 4 adjacent places but it is taking too much time.

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you want or give a link to supporting material. I have no idea what you try to achieve..

Comment: First we need to find out the number of island and that 1's form single island which are connected either up down or right left no diagonally connections are valid. So when we find such an island we need to make boundary around it. So total length of the boundary. If we take a side of cell to be unit.

Comment: For eg: the 1 at (1,1) share 1 side with 0 , 1 with 1 and 2 with matrix boundary.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A."For eg: the 1 at (1,1) share 1 side with 0 , 1 with 1 and 2 with matrix boundary." This is clear. What you are trying to calculate is not clear. B. Add explanations to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55546522/edit), and not as comments.  C. " I applied simple bfs and checked all 4 adjacent places but it is taking too much time" post your code as [mcve]. It should not take much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the changes from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 for each row and column in the matrix.

[image]

The edges of the matrix you can count as zero. 
For row 0, we have changes from 0 => 1=> 0 => 1 => 0. 4 changes.

For column 2, we have changes from 0 => 1 => 0. 2 changes.

Count all changes (crosses) together and you are done.

Comment: If this could be done by some other way. I am thinking of linear time solution or time less than O(nm). Like.. strongly connected components of directed graph , if some logic can be developed.

Comment: @Jagan_ Yes, it can be done faster. I know that because I reverse engineered your code to figure out the input format. Answers can only be as good as the question that you write. Next time, put a little more effort into actually explaining the problem that you're trying to solve.